# How to buid an extjs app for production?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to build for production an extjs4 app devolped with sencha architect.
Included in my app.html markup compiler directives  `<!-- <x-compile> -->`

I basically want my app and remote dependencies minimized.

Following this guideline:http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_app_single

I run

```
C:\temp\bs>sencha compile -classpath=..\ext\src,app page -yui -in app.html -out
build\app.html
```

but get:

```
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[INF] Compiling page null
[ERR] Error executing page compilation java.io.IOException: The filename, direct
ory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: java.io.IOException: The filename, director
y name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: are you using a server side technology like Java for the backend app?

Comment: My backend is asp.net webapi

Comment: anyway, i think you have to run that command from within your project directory.

Comment: I'm doing it. c:\temp\bs is my project directory.